# How to implement multiple product filters for ECommerce in Spring Boot, JavaScript, Ajax and MySql?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, e-commerce

I am working on an E-Commerce Web App using Spring Boot. So I have feature to add or apply multiple product filters. So there are multiple checkboxes, through that a user can check or select checkboxes according to his/her desire to filter or search product from store. **So, I got stuck that how it should be done from frontend.** So the filter options are ( Category, Tag, Subcategory, Minimum and Maximum Price, Discount, and Popularity). Suppose, a user has checked category then product inside the div should only be displayed according to selected category and If a user has checked category along with price range. **Example, Category -> Cake and Minimum Price -> Rs.300 and Maximum Price -> Rs.1000. So the product should be displayed according to that (Cake that comes under the price range of Rs.300 to 1000 only)**.

Below is my JavaScript function, that is holding all checkbox and input values:

```
    function updatelisting(){
                var min = document.getElementById("minprice").value;
                var max = document.getElementById("maxprice").value; 
                var c = new Array();
                var t = new Array();
                var s = new Array();
                var sp = new Array();
                var d = new Array();
                $('[id="checkbox1"]').each(function(i,e){
                    if($(e).is(':checked')){
                        c.push(e.value);
                    }
                })
                var category = c.toString();
                $('[id="checkbox2"]').each(function(i,e){
                    if($(e).is(':checked')){
                        t.push(e.value);
                    }
                })
                var tag = t.toString();
                $('[id="checkbox3"]').each(function(i,e){
                    if($(e).is(':checked')){
                        s.push(e.value);
                    }
                })
                var subcategory = s.toString();
                $('[id="checkbox5"]').each(function(i,e){
                    if($(e).is(':checked')){
                        sp.push(e.value);
                    }
                })
                var specialtag = sp.toString();
                $('[id="checkbox6"]').each(function(i,e){
                    if($(e).is(':checked')){
                        d.push(e.value);
                    }
                })
                var discount = d.toString();
                var url = "api/searchbyfilter";
                $.post(url,{
                    category : category,
                    tag : tag,
                    subcategory : subcategory,
                    specialtag : specialtag,
                    discount : discount,
                    min : min,
                    max : max, 
                }, function(data, status) {
                    if (data.status == "OK") {
                        if (data.statusCode == 1) {
                            console.log(data.response);
                            var list = data.response;
                            if(list.length == 0 || list.length == null){
                                alert("No product found");
                            }else{
                                $("#shop-1").html(selecttab(<%=pagelength%>));
                            }
                        } else {
                            var error = data.responseMessage;
                            swal(error, "", "error");
                        }
                    } else {
                        var error = data.responseMessage;
                        swal(error, "", "error");
                    }
                });
            }
```

**If anyone have suggestions or solutions, would be helpful for me. You can ask me for any doubt.**

[Screenshot to display filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TBLC.jpg)

[Screenshot to display filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzi8o.png)

Comment: You can trigger that function when user check the filters

Comment: Could you please explain some more?

Comment: You can add event listener on the filters and when users check filters it will trigger event function that you defined

Answer (score 0):

You can use event listener when you want to trigger some code you defined.

For instance when you want to print 'Hello World' whenever you click a button you can add click event listener on a button

```js
const button = $('#button');

button.on('click', function() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
});
```

The above code will print 'Hello World!' whenever you click the button.
So in the same approach you can add change event on filters which is checkbox

```js
const checkbox = $('#checkbox');

checkbox.on('change', function() {
    // The function you defined
    updatelisting();
});
```

Comment: Okay, I will try this approach too.